# Best way to check if all of the items in any of a list of lists are in a string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists like `mylist = [["1", "2"], ["abc", "def"]]` and a string like `mystr = "1 2"`.

I want to check if any of the lists in `mylist` have all of their strings in the string.

I have achieved this by doing the following.

```
if True in [all(keyword in mystr for keyword in keywords) for keywords in mylist]:
    print("yes")
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
matcher = mystr.__contains__
any(all(map(matcher, keywords)) for keywords in mylist)
```

Benchmarks:

```
>>> min(repeat(lambda: any(all(map(matcher, keywords)) for keywords in mylist), repeat=20))
1.1285329000002093
>>> min(repeat(lambda: any(all(map(mystr.__contains__, keywords)) for keywords in mylist), repeat=20))
1.2246240000004036
>>> min(repeat(lambda: any(all(keyword in mystr for keyword in keywords) for keywords in mylist), repeat=20))
1.3369910999999775
>>> min(repeat(lambda: True in [all(keyword in mystr for keyword in keywords) for keywords in mylist], repeat=20))
1.726889200000187
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `any`.

```
if any(all(keyword in mystr for keyword in keywords) for keywords in mylist):
    print("yes")
```

This is faster because it stops iterating (short-circuits) as soon as it sees a true value. It also has a side-benefit of being easier to read.

*Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) for mentioning this [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830401/best-way-to-check-if-all-of-the-items-in-any-of-a-list-of-lists-are-in-a-string/59830464#comment105797306_59830401)*